# How to display an image instead of text in the label of a form symfony5?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I would like to display an image instead of text in the label of a form on symfony5

I have an entity with a property image that is the link to the image I want to display. I can display it in the tables of my templates, but I need to display it in the label of the form.

Here is the code of  the formtype

```
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('limit_cost')
            ->add('total_cost')
           // ->add('commander')
            ->add('linkCombatUnit', EntityType::class, [
                "attr"=>[
                    'class'=>'form-control',
                    ],
                'class'=>CombatUnit::class,
                'choice_label'=>'name',
                
                'label_attr'=>['class'=>'me-1'],
                'label'=>'Choisir une unité de combat',
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded'=>true,
            ])
            ->add('secondary_stuff_add_btn', SubmitType::class, [
                'attr' => ['class' => 'secondary_stuff_add_btn'],
                'label' => 'Add Item',
            ])
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, [
                'attr' => ['class' => 'save'],
                'label' => 'Save',
            ])
```

the code of the form template which faile

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    {{ form_row(form.linkCombatUnit, {'label': <img src="{{ asset('/uploads/image_cards/' ~ combat_unit.card) }}" alt="" width='30px' >}) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

the code of the template edit where images display correctly

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Edit Army{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Edit Army</h1>
    {{ include('army/_form.html.twig', {'button_label': 'Update'}) }}
        <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                {# <th>Id</th> #}
                <th>Name of unit</th>
                <th>Card</th>
                <th>cost</th>
                <th>actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for lineArmy in lineArmies %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ lineArmy.combatUnit.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ lineArmy.combatUnit.cardVerso }}<img class='cardToEnlarge' src="{{ asset('/uploads/image_cards/' ~ lineArmy.combatUnit.cardVerso) }}" alt="" ></td>
                <td>{{ lineArmy.combatUnit.cost }}</td>
                <td>
{#                     <a href="{{ path('app_army_show', {'id': army.id}) }}">show</a>
                    <a href="{{ path('app_army_edit', {'id': army.id}) }}">edit</a> #}
                </td>
            </tr>
        {# {% else %} #}
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <a href="{{ path('app_army_index') }}">back to list</a>
<script src="{{ asset('/js/form_new_army.js') }}"></script>
    {{ include('army/_delete_form.html.twig') }}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of editing the label you can use the image as html in your form template like this

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    <img src="{{ asset('/uploads/image_cards/' ~ combat_unit.card) }}" alt="" width='30px'>
    {{ form_row(form.linkCombatUnit, {'label': false}) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```